# I have 1M records -some records are from data loader and there is no picklist restriction

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql, sosl

I have 1M records -some records are from data loader and there is no picklist restriction

I want to see uniuqe values for account object with that perticular values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aggregate SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) query and get the count

sample SOQL

```
Select AccountTypeField, Count(Id) from Account Group by AccountTypeField
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT Type, Count(Id) 
FROM Account
WHERE Type in ('Prosepct','Other','Customer direct')
GROUP BY Type
```

For more information, refer [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)